# GCC errors out on code that used to work fine

Tags: filenames, gcc

I have a program that has successfully compiled in the past, but now I get a bunch of errors.The source code is just:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    fd = creat("datafile.dat", S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);
    if (fd == -1)
        printf("Error in opening datafile.dat\n");
    else
    {
        printf("datafile.dat opened for read/write access\n");
        printf("datafile.dat is currently empty\n");
    }
    close(fd);
    exit (0);
}
```

Now I get the errors:

```
cre.C:8:54: error: ‘creat’ was not declared in this scope
cre.C:16:17: error: ‘close’ was not declared in this scope
cre.C:17:16: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
```

Sometimes I get an error about `gxx_personality_v0` instead, and sometimes I get no error at all! I've tried updating `gcc`, but the problem remains. What's going wrong?
OS UBUNTU 12.1 on vaio laptop

Comment: I *hope* you can understand how no one can take this seriously without a more concrete, reproducible demonstration of your problem(s).

Comment: In addition to goldilocks's comment, the error messages supplied suggest that the problem is with your code, making this a programming question, especially since you don't say which OS you are using.

Comment: No,I compiled it on another system successfully...

Comment: I believe Renan has the answer for you.  But for future reference, your question should have included relevant information about the system you were able to compile on.

Answer (score 5):

From your error messages I see that you called your file `cre.C`. gcc is case-sensitive for file names: try naming it `cre.c` and compiling it.

```
$ LANG=C cc -o foo foo.C
foo.C: In function 'int main()':
foo.C:8:54: error: 'creat' was not declared in this scope
foo.C:16:17: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
foo.C:17:16: error: 'exit' was not declared in this scope
```

but

```
$ LANG=C cc -o foo foo.c
foo.c: In function 'main':
foo.c:17:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' [enabled by default]
```

As noted in a comment, a file with `.C` extension is handled by the C++ compiler, thus you are seeing those errors.

Answer (score -1):

Read the man pages for the `creat`, `close`, and `exit` functions.

On my system, `creat()` requires:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

`close()` requires:

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

and `exit()` requires:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

As for why the code was compiling before, it's hard to tell. Perhaps the compiler was being invoked in a more permissive mode that didn't complain about missing function declarations, or perhaps some of the headers you do include have `#include` directives for the headers you need.

Comment: what about gxx_personality_v0?

Comment: @user1181065: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that. In any case, if you're using those functions, you should definitely include the required headers, even if it doesn't directly fix your problem. What happens when you add those `#include`s?